# Time Machine stuck in "copying" phase without number of bytes

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# tmutil status
Backup session status:
{
    BackupPhase = Copying;
    ClientID = "com.apple.backupd";
    DateOfStateChange = "2020-03-14 03:02:37 +0000";
    DestinationID = "D868A1F5-0393-4DA6-A8E6-467EBF374761";
    DestinationMountPoint = "/volumes/\U65f6\U95f4\U673a\U5668\U5907\U4efd";
    Percent = "-1";
    Running = 1;
    Stopping = 0;
    "_raw_Percent" = "-1";
}
```

I have never seen this before. I understand that the time machine needed deep scan because I force shutdown my computer. Here is the content of the logfile:

```
2020-03-14-10:09:59 - Starting backup

Previous snapshot:
    /volumes/时间机器备份/Backups.backupdb/Joy's MacBook Pro/2020-02-23-202330

Date of Previous snapshot: 1582460610164924

Will use FS events for "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
=== Starting backup loop #1 ===
  Will use IncrementalBackupCopier

Running preflight for "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
    Scanning nodes needing deep traversal
    Deep event scan at path: /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/Joy's MacBook Pro/2020-03-14-100956/MacOS High Sierra reason:must scan subdirs|new event db|
    Calculating size of changes
    Should copy 0 items (0 KB) representing 0 blocks of size 4096. 0 blocks available.
Preflight complete for "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
Time elapsed: 52 minutes, 13.000 seconds

Processing preflight info
    Space needed for this backup: 684 MB (166987 blocks of size 4096)
    Preserving last snapshot /volumes/时间机器备份/Backups.backupdb/Joy's MacBook Pro/2020-02-23-202330
Finished processing preflight info

Copying items from "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
```

For some reason it thinks that 0kb of file is needed to be copied. And even weirder, I found that there are 37 directories in the ".inprogress" directory, although the last backup was successful.

Now, when I stop the backup, it gives me some more information:

```
Copying items from "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
c :ERROR:-128, copy /Volumes/com.apple.TimeMachine.localsnapshots/Backups.backupdb/Joy's MacBook Pro/2020-03-14-100956/MacOS High Sierra to /volumes/时间机器备份/Backups.backupdb/Joy's MacBook Pro/2020-03-14-100957.inProgress/390A6822-2A2F-4400-9749-06647A6EA7D2
Finished copying items for "MacOS High Sierra" (device: /dev/disk1s1 mount: '/' fsUUID: 46E9EF82-FAC2-378D-BA1F-752302C51DDF eventDBUUID: F68A3161-3E94-400B-8944-E333113B9714)
Time elapsed: 10 hours, 39 minutes, 58.000 seconds
    Copied 1070645 items (116.65 GB)
    Copy stage canceled
```

Apparently it's trying to copy the whole disk? Just like the initial backup?

Update: This is not a filesystem error. I had run fsck over both my root volume (/) and the Time Machine backup bundle, and both outputs no error. In addition, I've rebuilt the attribute, catalog, and extents overflow tree with fsck, and that succeeded. Output is below:

```
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# hdiutil attach -nomount  /volumes/jin.local/volume1/Time\ Machine/Joy\'s\ MacBook\ Pro.sparsebundle
/dev/disk2              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk2s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk2s2            Apple_HFS                       
root@Joys-MacBook-Pro /p/v/root# fsck_hfs -dyf -Race -c 4g /dev/disk2s2

journal_replay(/dev/disk2s2) returned 0
** /dev/rdisk2s2
    Cache size should be greater than 32M and less than 17592186044415M
    Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=98304 cacheSize=3145728K.
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-407.50.6).
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
** Detected a case-sensitive volume.
   The volume name is 时间机器备份
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
** Rebuilding extents overflow B-tree.
hfs_UNswap_BTNode: invalid node height (1)
** Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
hfs_UNswap_BTNode: invalid node height (1)
** Rebuilding extended attributes B-tree.
hfs_UNswap_BTNode: invalid node height (1)
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
** Detected a case-sensitive volume.
   The volume name is 时间机器备份
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking catalog hierarchy.
** Checking extended attributes file.
** Checking multi-linked directories.
    privdir_valence=77292, calc_dirlinks=761825, calc_dirinode=77292
   Incorrect number of directory hard links
    Incorrect linkCount for inode=38898331 (expected=132, found=131)
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
   Invalid volume file count
   (It should be 16008002 instead of 14676628)
   Invalid volume directory count
   (It should be 956150 instead of 940755)
   Invalid volume free block count
   (It should be 2487156771 instead of 2529050918)
    invalid VHB nextCatalogID 
   Volume header needs minor repair
(2, 0)
   Verify Status: VIStat = 0x8000, ABTStat = 0x0000 EBTStat = 0x0000
                  CBTStat = 0x0000 CatStat = 0x00000001
** Repairing volume.
   Indirect node 38898331 needs link count adjustment
   (It should be 132 instead of 131)
** Rechecking volume.
** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
** Detected a case-sensitive volume.
   The volume name is 时间机器备份
** Checking extents overflow file.
** Checking catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking catalog hierarchy.
** Checking extended attributes file.
** Checking multi-linked directories.
    privdir_valence=77292, calc_dirlinks=761825, calc_dirinode=77292
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume 时间机器备份 was repaired successfully.
    CheckHFS returned 0, fsmodified = 1
```

Comment: And this lasted for a couple of hours. I had started the backup in the morning and now it's nighttime.

Comment: Do you have Disk Warrior? That would be my first port of call on a borked Time Machine, especially on High Sierra where I've seen it happen a lot.